# CSS expand div right floated div

Tags: css, html, css-float, clearfix

I have a main `div` **(purple)** for this html header which splits in 2 other divs contaning the logo **(red)** and some other information on the right **(green)**

I have a clear fix for **purple** which makes both **red** and **green** float nicelly, both are floated to the left.

[image]

the problem here is that I am struggling to find a way to make **green** fits the entire width

in this case the **red** itself has `199px` fixed width and no width declaration for **green**

the outer **purple** div doesn't have a fixed width too, it is at the moment **65%** of the `body` which has a fluid layout

So my question is: how to make the **green** `div` expand till the end of **purple** `div` with css?

I've tried to apply a `width:86%` for **green** but it didn't work since **red** has a fixed value...

I thought that perhaps there is some table display mode like `display:table-cell/table-row` or something like this that could solve the problem but none of them seemed to work the way I want.

If you could help me on that it would be great :)

Comment: The link to your image is broken, could you perhaps put the html up on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: @Graham Conzett just fixed this link, should work fine now...actually the code in this case doesn't matter to much you will see that its a very simple thing to achieve, but if you have any problems please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be pretty, but it should work.

1. Absolutely position the red div at 0,0
2. Add a padding-left of 199px to the purple div
3. Remove the float's from both the red and green divs

Answer (score 0):

Just using a `float: left` on the red div does the trick.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jk5BE/2/

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite solution for this type of problem, bonus is that it doesn't even use a wrapper and you can add other columns (although it looks like in your case a wrap will be needed since this looks like a header):

http://www.alistapart.com/d/holygrail/example_4.html

You could do it very simply just using a simple float as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/W3DEC/

Comment: hey Graham, thanks for the tip but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work when you have multiple lines. I've just updated your snippet at http://jsfiddle.net/W3DEC/2/ note that when the right div has more than one line it seems only the first line floats and the second stay bellow :( if I this could be fixed I am pretty sure I would use it all the time, meanwhile I had to adopt tilleryj answer which is not pretty as he said but works quite well.

Comment: Correct, from your example image it looked like the two sections shared a common height, if you just set that implicitly it works: http://jsfiddle.net/W3DEC/3/